# Output Builded.exe visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

So, I'm coding a chat, and I'm testing it over 2 computer, I've setup a box folder so when I drop the `builded.exe` in it the other computer have it available.

My question is : is there anyway to put it automatically in a specified folder every time I build the program?

Comment: Post build event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a post build script. This is just a Windows batch (aka. command) script. You can easily set it to copy from the output folder (VS adds macros so that does not need to be hardcoded) to wherever you can access.

Comment: Okk, let me try it, I guess it's in the build property right ?

Comment: @Mokmeuh: Yes, for a C# project under Build Events in the project properties. Other project types may vary.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned you can use post build event for that. You can use something like below in the post build event to copy the build output to the location you want.

```
copy $(TargetPath) "c:\Output"
```